# Jquery delay() lock and intercept

Tags: jquery

I am using this to execute a display and then then after 10 seconds destroy it. It has an "x" close function if you want to close it early then destroy_example() will kill it. It will not call it though.

I did a little testing and I have narrowed it down to the delay() in function create_example() seems to lock the id, other functions will call but I can not execute it early.

```
function create_example(){
    $("#my_example_id"+).fadeIn( 500 ).delay(10000).fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); });
    return false;
    }

function destroy_example(){
    $("#my_example_id").fadeOut(200, function() { $(this).remove(); });
    return false;
    }
```

Here is a JSFIDDLE example: http://jsfiddle.net/ymtc1z6k/4/

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would recommend that you revise and edit your question. As it is, it is currently it lacks sufficient information to offer you any assistance. Adding more details or a minimal example using jsFiddle.net or plnkr.co will help us help you help yourself :) Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations are appended to a queue. You can abort the current animation and clear the queue with [**`.stop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

```
$("#my_example_id").stop(true).fadeOut(200, ...);
```

From the documentation:

> If more than one animation method is called on the same element, the later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element. These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When `.stop()` is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately. If the `clearQueue` parameter is provided with a value of `true`, then the rest of the animations in the queue are removed and never run.

Comment: you sir...are amazing. Id +1 you for the reference but I am unable to lol

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
function create_example(){
  $("#my_example_id"+).fadeIn( 500 );
  return false;
}

function destroy_example(){
  $("#my_example_id").fadeOut(200, function() { $(this).remove(); });
  return false;
}

$(function() {
 create_example();
 setTimeout( destroy_example, 10000);
});
```